# Sony RemoteAPI delays after starting Liveview

Tags: c#, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Good worktime!

I'm writing C# warp around Sony Remote API, using Android test app as an example.

There became a problem with Liveview.

I start liveview streaming by the API method "startLiveview". Liveview data consumer works in a separate thread and it simply passes through frames if there's no time to draw them all (just like in the test app, as far as i understand).

However, after the startLiveview method is processed and fetching stream is started, the camera experience some difficulties with all other API commands processing in time.

E.g., after my warp discovers the camera and connects to it, performs startRecMode and so on, it can take pictures very fast. However, since liveview is started, the camera can't process all actTakePicture calls in time. There can be seconds or even dozens of seconds i have to wait before the shutter clicks.

I've tried to stop liveview before starting picture taking. It doesn't matter - stopLiveview command experiences the same problem, it takes even minutes to process it (there are minutes to return from System.Net.WebClient.UploadString).

I've tried to use startLiveviewWithSize instead of startLiveview and to pass the smallest size available (there is "M" with Sony A7R i'm using). No result.
What can i do to successfully stop the liveview or, as a max wish, to get rid of performance penalties when the liveview is on?

Thank you in advance!

p.S. Using MS VS 2010, .NET Framework 3.5, Sony ILCE Alpha 7R camera, all preprocessing settings found are switched off.

Comment: I'm playing with the Sony Camera API too since a few time. This thing really depends on the camera and firmware, and I own a NEX-6 and a6000. I'm seeing this delay too, even though not as much as you (it's a matter of several seconds). I think that it could be a problem of the Sony camera firmware. I suggest to try the Sony official app PlayMemories from the camera store and see how it behaves. In my case,

Comment: Sorry, I probably hit the button before finishing. In my case, the cameras are sluggish even with the official Sony app.