# Sony remote app on C#. stucked after trying liveview

Tags: c#, sony, sony-camera-api

So here is my question. I am trying to use the sony remote camera API SDK as a guide for developing a simple program in Visual studio using C# and controlling a SDCQX-10. I tried to use the kz-remote app... but couldn't get around with it. So I decided to get it done by using network sockets.
It was wonderful, at the beginning, but after a while I decided to give it a try to liveviewing... Then everything crashed. I mean, by everything, The camera stopped responding. I managed to get the lenses "closed and opened again (retract)" by removing the battery and inserting it again and switching the camera on, but then, when trying to take a picture the camera stopped responding again.
OK so, after some workaround here are the symptoms (camera is Updated to V3.0 firmware):

-The camera turns on normally, by manual control you can zoom in and out
-When the shutter is pressed it takes a while for it to make the "take picture" sound (Although no picture is taken)
-After the "Take picture" sound is heard, the red led indicator (Access lamp) keeps lit (ON)
-After the shutter is pressed, the camera does not respond (The zoom in/out is disabled, shutter does not respond either)
-When turning off the lens doesn't retract

When using the PlayMemories Android App (Version 5.7.0, spanish. Android V. 6.0.1 Asus Zenphone 2 Laser (ASUS_Z00TD) *Previously working OK with Playmemories)

-The camera connects "normally"
-No liveview is available (black screen with controls superposed)
-Zoom in/out works from the android device
-Something that will translate as "Cannot obtain direct visualization image" is displayed after some time
-When remote shutter is pressed all the symptoms above described for the manual shutter happen as well.

Finally, I tried to check what was happening when using the program:
I use the following code on a button to connect the camera (SDDP to discover the camera and retrieve the information)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 60000);
        IPEndPoint MulticastEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250"), 1900);

        Socket UdpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        UdpSocket.Bind(LocalEndPoint);

        textBox1.AppendText("UDP-Socket setup done...\r\n");

        string SearchString = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1\r\nMX:3\r\n\r\n";

        UdpSocket.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SearchString), SocketFlags.None, MulticastEndPoint);

        textBox1.AppendText("M-Search sent...\r\n");

        byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[64000];

        int ReceivedBytes = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (UdpSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                ReceivedBytes = UdpSocket.Receive(ReceiveBuffer, SocketFlags.None);

                if (ReceivedBytes > 0)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceivedBytes));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

After which I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1800
EXT: 
LOCATION: http://10.0.0.1:64321/DmsRmtDesc.xml
SERVER: UPnP/1.0 SonyImagingDevice/1.0
ST: urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1
USN: uuid:00000000-0005-0010-8000-1c994c0c5152::urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1
X-AV-Physical-Unit-Info: pa=""; pl=;
X-AV-Server-Info: av=5.0; hn=""; cn="Sony Corporation"; mn="SonyImagingDevice"; mv="1.0";
```

I used this script on another button in order to test different functions:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.0.1:10000/sony/camera ");
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = "POST";
                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
                string postData = "{\"method\": \""+textBox2.Text+"\",\"params\": [],\"id\": 1,\"version\": \"1.0\"}";

                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
                // Get the response.
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                // Display the status.
                textBox1.AppendText(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.
                textBox1.AppendText(responseFromServer);
                var fot = responseFromServer.Substring(20).Split('\"').FirstOrDefault();
                //textBox2.AppendText(fot);
                // Clean up the streams.
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(fot);
                // Follow intruction to try to visualize the image
                //var client = new WebClient();
                //client.DownloadFile(webBrowser1.Url, @"c:/foto.jpg");
                //using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(dat))
                //{
                //    using (var im = Image.FromStream(mem))
                //    {
                //        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap) im;
                //    }
                //}
                //pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:/foto.jpg");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

It worked fine to take pictures, I commented the few last lines, I used them to retrieve the picture (I'm leaving them there because until then it was working OK, for taking the picture and visualizing it)

SO, i have no data before the crash (Shame on me)... But after, here are some responses for the API:

**actTakePicture**

```
OK{"error":[40403,"Long shooting"],"id":1}
```

then (When pressed a second time and on)

```
OK{"error":[5,""],"id":1}
```

**awaitTakePicture**

`OK{"error":[40403,"Not Finished"],"id":1}` (Keeps on this after taking the Picture)

or

`OK{"error":[1,""],"id":1}` (It appears a bit random in between the above and this one when no picture has been taken)

**getEvent**

using: `\"params\": [false]`

```
OK{"id":1,"result":[{"names":["getMethodTypes","getAvailableApiList","setShootMode","getShootMode","getSupportedShootMode","getAvailableShootMode","setSelfTimer","getSelfTimer","getSupportedSelfTimer","getAvailableSelfTimer","setPostviewImageSize","getPostviewImageSize","getSupportedPostviewImageSize","getAvailablePostviewImageSize","startLiveview","stopLiveview","actTakePicture","startMovieRec","stopMovieRec","awaitTakePicture","actZoom","setExposureMode","getExposureMode","getSupportedExposureMode","getAvailableExposureMode","setBeepMode","getBeepMode","getSupportedBeepMode","getAvailableBeepMode","setCameraFunction","getCameraFunction","getSupportedCameraFunction","getAvailableCameraFunction","setStillSize","getStillSize","getSupportedStillSize","getAvailableStillSize","actFormatStorage","getStorageInformation","setTouchAFPosition","cancelTouchAFPosition","getTouchAFPosition","getSupportedExposureCompensation","getSupportedWhiteBalance","getSupportedIsoSpeedRate","actHalfPressShutter","cancelHalfPressShutter","getApplicationInfo","getVersions","getEvent"],"type":"availableApiList"},{"cameraStatus":"IDLE","type":"cameraStatus"},{"type":"zoomInformation","zoomIndexCurrentBox":0,"zoomNumberBox":1,"zoomPosition":0,"zoomPositionCurrentBox":0},{"liveviewStatus":true,"type":"liveviewStatus"},{"liveviewOrientation":"0","type":"liveviewOrientation"},[{"takePictureUrl":[],"type":"takePicture"}],[],{"triggeredError":[],"type":"triggeredError"},{"motionRecognition":"None","sceneRecognition":"None","steadyRecognition":"None","type":"sceneRecognition"},{"formatResult":"","type":"formatStatus"},[{"numberOfRecordableImages":1228,"recordTarget":true,"recordableTime":-1,"storageDescription":"Storage Media","storageID":"Memory Card 1","type":"storageInformation"}],{"beepModeCandidates":["Shutter Only","On","Off"],"currentBeepMode":"On","type":"beepMode"},{"cameraFunctionCandidates":["Remote Shooting","Contents Transfer"],"currentCameraFunction":"Remote Shooting","type":"cameraFunction"},null,{"checkAvailability":true,"currentAspect":"4:3","currentSize":"18M","type":"stillSize"},{"cameraFunctionResult":"","type":"cameraFunctionResult"},null,null,{"currentExposureMode":"Intelligent Auto","exposureModeCandidates":["Intelligent Auto","Superior Auto","Program Auto"],"type":"exposureMode"},{"currentPostviewImageSize":"2M","postviewImageSizeCandidates":["2M","Original"],"type":"postviewImageSize"},{"currentSelfTimer":0,"selfTimerCandidates":[0,2,10],"type":"selfTimer"},{"currentShootMode":"still","shootModeCandidates":["still","movie"],"type":"shootMode"},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"currentSet":false,"currentTouchCoordinates":[],"type":"touchAFPosition"}]}
```

Well, I really hope that is enough information. And I really hope somebody can help me with this!!!!
A similar thread I found is:
[Sony RemoteAPI delays after starting Liveview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821766/sony-remoteapi-delays-after-starting-liveview)
But there were no answers.
Thank you all!!!

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what exactly the issue you are having is.  Sounds like the problem is that the camera functionality is not working as expected after you used the Camere Remote API, is that correct?  Did you try reflashing the firmware?

Comment: Nope. I tried to reload the firmware, but it was unsuccessful (Due it has already the latest version).  I don't actually know how to reflash the fimware (It was actually an option I talked about with one colleague), but didn't do extensive search on it. I would thank you very much if you can give me some advice about it. However, I took it to a fast checkout at technical service, although I didn't leave it there for a complete dx, they told me it might be the sensor connection which might have broken after use...

Comment: (And in brief, the camera functionality is not working as you said, a huge delay between pressing the button and the click sound (ca 15 seconds), and no picture is taken. Liveview in Playmemories not working either). Thank you very much Marlin!

Comment: Sounds like a HW problem as the technical service suggested.  The symptoms you are suggesting don't seem like they could be caused by the API and in any case a restart of the camera should reset any kind of bad state the camera could be in as a result of the API.

Comment: You were right Marlin, there was a HW problem, apparently the image sensor got detached from the shutter... Fortunately we had another camera in the lab, and now it is working as a char, (Although with a bit of rudimentary coding), now I am trying to use a proper JSON reader (Having some hard time with it, but it is not an API issue). Thank you very much!